# Problem of Low Accuracy of NeuralNetwork Method in Classify MNIST 11.3

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

The accuracy is extremely low... even after changing a lot of options of Method...
Other methods' result is fine and normal, 0.80 accuracy like `LogisticRegression`.
NetTrain works well

I've tried several hours in Linux/Max/Windows version of Mathematica 11.3

Where goes wrong?

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
trainSet = RandomSample[trainingData, 20000];
model1 = Classify[trainSet, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[model1, testData];
cm@"Accuracy"
```

[image]

Comment: How long did you allow it to train? Did you try just a bare `Classify` without the `Method`?

Comment: @CarlLange Other methods' result is Fine, 0.80 accuracy like LogisticRegression. TrainingTime is not the problem

Comment: Sorry, no idea. On my machine I get 0.9 accuracy with the same setup. By the way, please paste code into the question rather than a screenshot of the code. Nobody likes typing.

Comment: @CarlLange Code Added. What's your Mathematica Version? 11.3?

Comment: Yes, 11.3 on Mac.

Comment: @CarlLange I've found one of the reason. When I setting MaxTrainingRounds->5 0, Sometimes[not frequent] I can get good results.

Comment: @CarlLange I've found the key problem is the EarlyStopping Option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem is the EarlyStopping Option, I think the default setting of Automatic of EarlyStopping maybe True, This is not newbie-friendly.

[image]